# Extend "conv" instance in Node.js Client Library for Actions on Google v2 when using TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

In the Actions on **Google Node.js client library v2** there is a **middleware** that allows to add properties or helper classes to the `conv` instance. An Example from the official version 1 migration guide:

```
const { dialogflow } = require('actions-on-google');

class Helper {
  constructor(conv) {
    this.conv = conv;
  }

  func1() {
    this.conv.ask(`What's up?`);
  }
}

const app = dialogflow()
  .middleware(conv => {
    conv.helper = new Helper(conv);
  });

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
  conv.helper.func1();
});
```

This may work fine for plain JavaScript. But what if **TypeScript** is used?

If the code is written in Typescript, TSC complains about the lines `conv.helper = new Helper(conv);` and `conv.helper.func1();`:

> [ts] Property 'helper' does not exist on type 'DialogflowConversation<{}, {}, Contexts>'.

Maybe I could rewrite it to `(<any>conv).helper`, but that's pretty ugly. Does anyone know a (better) solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`dialogflow`](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/d7ef56e0bb2c5e6fe3439a4c0198141c57136f44/src/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.ts#L257) app creation function is overloaded with generic type parameters that allow you to override the Conversation type sent through the intent handler.

You just need to create a type extending the appropriate Conversation type. It is much more complicated in order to keep all the type security but it's doable.

So the snippet you shared in TypeScript in the most type secure and generic implementation would be:

```js
import {
  dialogflow,
  DialogflowConversation,
  DialogflowMiddleware,
  Contexts,
} from 'actions-on-google';

// an interface with the extensions to the Conversation type
interface HelperConversation<
  TData = {},
  TUserStorage = {},
  TContexts extends Contexts = {},
> extends DialogflowConversation<TData, TUserStorage, TContexts> {
  helper: Helper<TData, TUserStorage, TContexts>;
}

// the helper class now passing generic type parameters from the Conversation type
class Helper<TData, TUserStorage, TContexts extends Contexts> {
  constructor(public conv: DialogflowConversation<TData, TUserStorage, TContexts>) {}

  func1() {
    this.conv.ask(`What's up?`);
  }
}

// to keep type security in the middleware, it needs to be functional and of the DialogflowMiddleware type
const middleware: DialogflowMiddleware<HelperConversation> =
  conv => Object.assign(conv, { helper: new Helper(conv) })

// pass the extended Conversation interface into the `dialogflow` function
const app = dialogflow<HelperConversation>()
  .middleware(middleware);

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
  // now conv is of the type `HelperConversation`
  conv.helper.func1();
});
```

Depending on how secure/generic you want the TypeScript middleware to be, you can get rid of a lot of the extra generic parameters with basic Object types which cuts back on a lot of the code.

You can also take a look at the TypeScript code snippets shared during the alpha for more detailed usages of TypeScript with the library:

- [Example TypeScript Plugin](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/935d0f9adfe78a4f9eb83ab4bb0fb9f6a7db2001/samples/ts/snippet/plugin/localize.ts#L21)
- [Example TypeScript Plugin Usage](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/935d0f9adfe78a4f9eb83ab4bb0fb9f6a7db2001/samples/ts/snippet/snippets.ts#L33)

Comment: That helped me a lot, thank you so much Shuyang. The `Object.assign()` seems to be missing the source object, so I changed it to `conv => Object.assign(conv, { helper: new Helper(conv) })`. Unfortunately I then get the error "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON", which is probably due to the `conv` instance in `new Helper(conv)`. Any idea how to get rid of that?

Comment: Ah, ty for noticing the mistake, I edited it. The error you are getting is most likely a bug that was just fixed with the latest release 2.1.2 https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/issues/152. Try upgrading to 2.1.2 to see it it's fixed now.